# An input field to allow an editor to select a Schema or Category

Tags: cme, schema, categories

I'm designing a schema. I'd like to insert a select/dropdown, which lists all the schemas in the current publication. (Could be limited to public-content schemas I guess)

I have the same question about categories: I'd like a select/dropdown which lists all categories.

**Use case:**

A "navigation builder". We would have a "navigation" component. Inside, the content editor can select a category and one or more schemas, and the CM will deliver a list of components using that schema which are tagged with any keyword from that category, such that the website can build a navigation menu.

From looking at the Tridion UI, and searching here on Stack Exchange, I assume this is not possible - but I'd like confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a decade ago, @BartKoopman shared the [Item Selector Custom URL](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/item-selector-custom-url-extension/638/) which can be set for a field's Custom URL in the Schema definition.

Per the comments to https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/21645/46 @
MariovanderHoeven-Riesebos has since updated it to work for Sites 9.0 with some Bootstrap functionality support and some nice options for the format to store the selected item. :-)

The idea with this approach is to let users click on the field description to get a pop-up that lets them pick the right item. This item is then stored in the text field as a TCM URI (or now WebDAV URL or ID) which implementers can then use in the CMS or in Content Delivery, published in a format your application can consume.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at this from a least technical impact and editorially driven perspective:

Have the schemas you want selectable as a list of keywords.

Map the schemas to query  to the keywords selected through the key with the schema ID or {mapping to} the WebDAV url

You’d the  run the query/filter based on the exposed keys from the selected keywords.

Note that the keys cannot be updated in most instances once they are created/used IIRC

Answer (score 3):

No, out of the box it is not possible. If you need to create this kind of component, you have 2 options I think.

The first option is to create a custom page, where you will have a custom app that does exactly what you want with Core Service in the background creating components by some criteria.

The second option would be to extend Tridion UI by creating UI extension where you would add a dropdown for category selection and then provide the list of components based on that. This would be in my opinion a lot more complicated to implement, but it might be good option to explore.

Comment: To help with the item selection part, @BartKoopman shared the [Item Selector Custom URL](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/item-selector-custom-url-extension/638/) a while back to let users select a certain type of item, such as a Schema or Category, using a field's Custom Url link. ;-)

Comment: @alvin that comment would be valid as an answer, and a while back? Try more than 10 years ago :p

Comment: Thanks all, we'll look into this!

Comment: @BartKoopman I have updated that implementation for a client running 9.0, it can now return ID, TcmUri and WebdavUrl for the selected item. Also, I have added Bootstrap support (popOver and dialog supported).

https://bitbucket.org/gkameel/sdl-tridion-world/src/sync/Item%20Selector/trunk/SDLTridion.Examples.ItemSelector/

Comment: I added an answer (with "over 10 years"), Bart. ;-) And nice updates, @MariovanderHoeven-Riesebos.